struggeling to use keyloak as idp for salesforce (signed JWT): PublicKey wasn't found in the storage
My task is to set up keycloak as an authentication endpoint for an external app in Salesforce (SF is being managed by another company). Salesforce is responsible for generating a signed JWT (with a given certificate), which it then sends to keycloak to obtain a valid access token.
To implement this, I received a certificate and a JKS with a PrivateKeyEntry. The current issue is the "kid" parameter in the header of the generated token, which specifies the correct key id . This key id however cannot be found by Keycloak. 
Error Message:
[org.keycloak.keys.infinispan.InfinispanPublicKeyStorageProvider] (executor-thread-93) PublicKey wasn't found in the storage. Requested kid: 'KEY_ID' . Available kids: '[9ABAWiSDn7yWJ1XwsXse7yUeEYx0abMVBXlq-0SvKAs]'
This is how I set up the client:

In the "Credentials" tab the client authenticator is set to "Signed JWT"
The Signature algorith is set to "RS256" which is correct

Than I went into the "Keys" Tab, clicked on "Import" and imported the JKS file which was successfull.
I suspect that in "Realm Settings" -> "Keys" -> "Keys list" there should be a key with the missing "kid"? I tried adding a provider using the JKS, which resulted in this error: Error saving provider: Failed to load keys. Invalid certificate chain. Check the order of certificates.
What am I missing here?
